# Android driver development

Tags: android, printing, driver

I am planning to create a system for shops. I am going to use an android tablet and a receipt printer. The printer I am planning to use does not support Android.

**My question is:**

- Can I create a driver for the printer?
- Do I need to know anything about the printer such as (chip or any other electronic stuff)
- Is it difficult to create the driver?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure your printer doesn't support in Android? There are some sdk's available which enables Android to connect with different printers. Like [this](http://www.isb-vietnam.com.vn/android-printing-framework/index.php) and [this](http://www.iprintsdk.com/index.html)

Comment: I haven`t tried but that is what it says in the description. I mean it does not say anything about Linux or Android. It says about different versions of Windows.

Comment: That only means it only natively supports windows.. How are you intenting to communicate with the printer ? Bluetooth or wifi?

Comment: I am planning to use the USB

Comment: USB I am not sure. I had a similar requirement, but the medium was bluetooth. It was very easy. I connected to the printer, send the message as a string, and It print as it is. You can format and play with printer language to format what you need to print. I am not  sure about the USB part though.

Comment: I haven`t noticed your message. I am looking for a cheap option. something like this or similar. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Loftek-Thermal-Printer-Support-Cartridges/dp/B006W2DQMO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359576392&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid this setup. The words *shop* and *receipt* sound as if some reliability and user friendliness are required. Today, communication with printers is mostly bi-directional because they send all kinds of information back. Processing at least some of these (toner low, out of paper) would certainly help your users. Apart from that, reverse engineering a specific printer's protocol isn't necessarily fun, especially should you not be experienced with respect to printer protocols. Also, low cost printers delegate all kinds of logic to the driver because this lowers the costs for the device. I would not rely on related documentation being available.

A good indication whether the printer of your choice is suitable at all may be if it's supported by some open source printing framework. Such a framework could also be your first address for answers to related questions.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best choice would be to firstly try some open-source printer software which might work with this printer. If any open-source software doesn't work, you would get a good understanding after going over the open-source driver for another similar printer.

You would not be needing to know information about the chip and other electronic stuff to write a driver. Although, you would need a documentation of the printer which says the protocol the printer follows.

I don't think that it should be really tough writing a driver for a printer, although it depends on how much flexible driver you want to write. If you want to write a driver which just fulfils the specialized jobs you want it to do, the driver should not be tough to write although the driver could not then be extended beyond the requirements of your application and not used for any generic use. If you want to write a generic driver which can be used to print anything, then it might not be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely positively have to use the specific printer model? Because if not, you may want to take a look at [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/). You will need to have a compatible app for Android(and there's plenty of those, the list is available [here](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/apps.html)) and a cloud ready printer(again, there's many of them, you can find the list [here](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html)), or a conventional printer, there is a way to connect those as well.